# Retrieving Data from FireStore using MVVM Architecture

Tags: java, android, firebase, mvvm, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to follow Android Architecture principles and would like you implement them on top of my FireStore database.

Currently I have a repository `Class` that handles all my queries with the underlying data. I have a `Fragment` that requires a `Set<String>` of keys from the fields in a document and am wondering what the best approach to retrieve this data is. In my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54454525/how-to-return-keyset-from-a-documentsnapshot) [Alex Mamo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5246885/alex-mamo) suggested using an `Interface` in conjunction with an `onCompleteListener` since retrieval of data from Firestore is `Asynchronous`.

This approach seems to work but I am unsure of how to extract the data from this `Interface` to a variable local to my `Fragment`. If I wish to use this data would my code have to be within my definition of the `abstract` method?

Am I still following MVVM principle if to get the data from Firestore to my `Fragment` I have to pass an `Interface` object defined in a Fragment as a parameter to my repository?

Is this the recommended approach for querying a Firestore database using a Repository?

Below is my `Interface` and method that calls on a `ViewModel` to retrieve data:

```
public interface FirestoreCallBack{
    void onCallBack(Set<String> keySet);
}

public void testMethod(){
    Log.i(TAG,"Inside testMethod.");
    mData.getGroups(new FirestoreCallBack() {
    //Do I have to define what I want to use the data for here (e.g. display the contents of the set in a textview)?
        @Override
        public void onCallBack(Set<String> keySet) {
            Log.i(TAG,"Inside testMethod of our Fragment and retrieved: " + keySet);
            myKeySet = keySet;
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Retrieved from interface: "+ myKeySet,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

My `ViewModel` method to call on the Repository:

```
private FirebaseRepository mRepository;
public void getGroups(TestGroupGetFragment.FirestoreCallBack firestoreCallBack){
    Log.i(TAG,"Inside getGroups method of FirebaseUserViewModel");
    mRepository.getGroups(firestoreCallBack);
}
```

Finally my Repository method to `query` my FireStore database:

```
public void getGroups(final TestGroupGetFragment.FirestoreCallBack firestoreCallBack){
    Log.i(TAG,"Attempting to retrieve a user's groups.");
    userCollection.document(currentUser.getUid()).get().addOnCompleteListener(
            new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                        Log.i(TAG,"Success inside the onComplete method of our document .get() and retrieved: "+ document.getData().keySet());
                        firestoreCallBack.onCallBack(document.getData().keySet());
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG,"The .get() failed for document: " + currentUser.getUid(), task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
    Log.i(TAG, "Added onCompleteListener to our document.");
}
```

EDITED

```
public void testMethod(){
    Log.i(TAG,"Inside testMethod.");
    mData.getGroups(new FirestoreCallBack() {
        @Override
        public void onCallBack(Set<String> keySet) {
            Log.i(TAG,"Inside testMethod of our Fragment and retrieved: " + keySet);
            myKeySet = keySet;
            someOtherMethod(myKeySet); //I know I can simply pass keySet.
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"GOT THESE FOR YOU: "+ myKeySet,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    Log.i(TAG,"In testMethod, retrieving the keySet returned: "+ myKeySet);
}
```

Comment: Making that `myKeySet` variable global, doesn't mean that can be simply used outside the `onCallBack` method, it's still in the callback.

Comment: So in order to pass `myKeySet` to another method, I have to call that method inside the `onCallBack` method? Please review the edited portion of my original question.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, you have to call it inside the `onCallBack` method.

Comment: Thank you for the help Alex. Would you happen to know if this `Interface` approach is the best method for using a Repository to abstract from an underlying FireStore database?

Comment: I don't know what to say if this is the best approach but If it solves you problem, it's worth to use it.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of `interface` I only use `LiveData` to bring the data to a recyclerview, for example.

First, We have to create our `Firestore query`. In this example, I am listing all documents inside a collection.

```
public class FirestoreLiveData<T> extends LiveData<T> {

    public static final String TAG = "debinf firestore";

    private ListenerRegistration registration;

    private CollectionReference colRef;
    private Class clazz;

    public FirestoreLiveData(CollectionReference colRef, Class clazz) {
        this.colRef = colRef;
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }


    EventListener<QuerySnapshot> eventListener = new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            if (e != null) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Listen failed.", e);
                return;
            }


            if (queryDocumentSnapshots != null && !queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {
                List<T> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (DocumentSnapshot snapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments()) {
                    T item = (T) snapshot.toObject(clazz);
                    itemList.add(item);
                    Log.i(TAG, "snapshot is "+snapshot.getId());
                }
                setValue((T) itemList);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onActive() {
        super.onActive();
        registration = colRef.addSnapshotListener(eventListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onInactive() {
        super.onInactive();
        if (!hasActiveObservers()) {
            registration.remove();
            registration = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Next, we create a link in our `Repository`

```
public class Repository {

    public Repository() {
    }

    public LiveData<List<ProductsObject>> productListening(GroupObject group) {
        return new FirestoreLiveData<>(DatabaseRouter.getCollectionRef(group.getGroupCreator()).document(group.getGroupKey()).collection("ProductList"), ProductsObject.class);
    }

}
```

After that, we create our `ViewModel`:

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {

    Repository repository = new Repository();

    public LiveData<List<ProductsObject>> getProductList(GroupObject groupObject) {
        return repository.productListening(groupObject);
    }

}
```

And finally, in our `MainActivity` or `Fragment` we observe the data contained in ou Firestore:

```
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
    viewModel.getProductList(groupObject).observe(this, new Observer<List<ProductsObject>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<ProductsObject> productsObjects) {
            //Log.i(TAG, "viewModel: productsObjects is "+productsObjects.get(0).getCode());
            adapter.submitList(productsObjects);
        }
    });
```

I hope it helps.